# count button clicks

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I want to count the number of times the button is clicked using GUI.

I did this code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
 {                                         
  int clicked = 0;
  clicked++;
  System.out.println(clicked);
 }
```

But it showing the output "1", each time I click the button.

I want every time I click the button to show me the count.

ex: If I click the button two times it should give me output of "2".

Answer (score 7):

You are resetting the counter every time you click, because you have defined the variable inside the action method. Try not doing that.

```
int clicked = 0; // move this outside
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                         
    // int clicked = 0; -- this resets it to 0 each time
    clicked++;
    System.out.println(clicked);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You've declared `clicked` as a local variable, initialised to `0`, it can never be anything else but `1`

Make `clicked` a class level variable instead...

```
private int clicked = 0;

//...

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                         
    clicked++;
    System.out.println(clicked);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try below code

```
int clicked = 0;
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
 {                                         

  clicked++;
  System.out.println(clicked);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
int clicked = 0;
```

to be a member of your class. This way it wont be set to zero every time you press the button.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `count` variable inside the `ActionListener`. Declare it outside the block.

```
int clicked = 0;  //make it as your class member.
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                         

  clicked++;
  System.out.println(clicked);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you are instantiating this class you need to declare the `clicked` variable at either the field level or the class variable level.  Currently, the scope of the `clicked` variable is local to the method.

**Option 1**

```
int clicked = 0;

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
 {                                         
  clicked++;
  System.out.println(clicked);
 }
```

**Option 2**

```
static int clicked = 0;

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
 {                                         
  clicked++;
  System.out.println(clicked);
 }
```

The option you use will depend on instantiation.  The second option should be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 2):

every time `jButton1ActionPerformed` fires, the clicked variables gets instantiated back to 0  that's why it is always giving you a value of 1. You should move the `clicked` variable outside of that method

```
//Somewhere in your class
private intClicked = 0;
//More methods here.

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
 {                                         
  clicked++;
  System.out.println(clicked);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


public class Threading extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField DisplayOne;
    private JTextField DisplayTwo;

    int count;
    int count1;
    int count2;


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() 
            {
                  try {
                    Threading frame = new Threading();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */


    public Threading() 
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        DisplayOne = new JTextField();
        panel.add(DisplayOne);
        DisplayOne.setColumns(10);

        DisplayTwo = new JTextField();
        panel.add(DisplayTwo);
        DisplayTwo.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnCountOne = new JButton("Count 1");
        count1=0;
        btnCountOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {                
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
                {   
                    DisplayOne.setText(Integer.toString(count1++));
                }
        });
        panel.add(btnCountOne);

        JButton btnCountTwo = new JButton("Count 2");
        count2=0;
        btnCountTwo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
            {
                DisplayTwo.setText(Integer.toString(count2++));
            }
        });
        panel.add(btnCountTwo);

        JButton btnCountBoth = new JButton("Count Both");
        count=0;
        btnCountBoth.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
            {
                while (count < 10)
                {
                DisplayOne.setText(Integer.toString(++count));
                DisplayTwo.setText(Integer.toString(count));
                }
            }
        });
        panel.add(btnCountBoth);
    }

}
```