# how to put two event handlers for two consecutive mouse clicks?

Tags: java, eventhandler

I want to put two event handlers for two consecutive clicks like chess,
I have done it like this and it works...
but I want to do it in separate event handlers.

```
void handleMouseClick(){

  if (clicked){

  clicked = false;

  }
  else if(!clicked){
     clicked = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Consider counting the clicks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999392/count-button-clicks     and using click count.

Comment: Not clear, you want to catch double-clicks, or a selection click, then a deselection click?

Comment: @user1803551  a selection click, then a deselection click

Comment: In that case you have to give a [mcve], because you're not showing how you're storing the selected state.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [counting the clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999392/count-button-clicks) and using click count:

```
        //counter field
        private int clicked = 0;

        private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
         {                                         
           clicked++;

           switch (clicked) {

           case 1:
               //respond
               break;
           case 2:
               //respond
               break;

           }
         }
```